# Creating route shapefile based on start and end mile markers in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, linear-referencing, route, arcgis-10.8

I am using ArcMap 10.8.

I have an Excel file of road condition data that contains a `ROUTE_ID` field as well as beginning and end mile post values. I also have an existing line shapefile that contains a matching `ROUTE_ID` field as well as several other attribute fields I need to maintain. The condition data file has hundreds of segments per `ROUTE_ID`, so I don't believe I can just do a simple Add Join based on the `ROUTE_ID` field and the fact that I need it to be spatially accurate.

I think the best way to do it would be to use the mile post beginning and ends to create a separate shapefile (this is the part I don't know how to do), then do a spatial join to get the attributes to line up properly.

Comment: Have you investigated Linear Referencing?

Comment: I have tried to search how to use linear referencing for this, but I haven't found anything on creating the new shapefile from the relative locations in the Excel spreadsheet. I saw plenty for if I were creating features along an existing route, but I couldn't figure out how to append the Excel attributes to the line file in the correct locations. Any insight if this is even possible?

Comment: You don't append or join anything when using linear referencing. Firstly confirm your line shapefile is PolylineM. If that is not then you need to fix that. Then simply use the [Make Route Event Layer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/linear-ref-toolbox/make-route-event-layer.htm) tool. to convert your Excel table into lines along the routes.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach for this did turn out to be the "Make Route Event Layer" tool as suggested by Hornbydd. My biggest issue was actually due to a couple blank spaces on my ROUTE_ID field causing a lot of errors where the route couldn't be found. I was able to fix this by creating a new Route_ID_S field and using the field calculator with !ROUTE_ID!.strip() to get rid of the extra spaces and 98% of my errors were corrected with just that.
Thank you to everyone who gave responses to help me figure this out!